# Does the "Developer Bootstrap" page work in IBM Connections 5?

Tags: opensocial, ibm-connections, ibm-sbt

Even for gadgets which work nicely elsewhere in IBM Connections, I'm getting the following error in my browser console:

```
 OAuth error: {"text":"","rc":403,"oauthError":"get_oauth2_accessor_problem","oauthErrorText":"","oauthErrorTrace":"\n","oauthErrorUri":"","oauthErrorExplanation":"An error occured. Ask your administrator to create an OAuth2.0 Client binding for this gadget and service.","errors":["403 Error"]}
```

I've followed the PDF guide [Developing OpenSocial gadgets for IBM Connections
4.0](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/dw/lotus/OS_gadget_IC4_final.pdf). Also, is this guide still valid for IC5?

Comment: I asked one of the technical leads to look at your update.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Bootstrap page still works in IBM Connections 5.0 
Be sure to edit your opensocial-config.xml (both in the deployment manager and appserver profiles)

Change any false attribute to

```
<developer allowIntranetProxyAccess="true" allowSSOFeature="true" enabled="true">
<developer-hosts-whitelist allServers="true">
```

Save the file

Restart the WidgetContainer App

It should all work then.

If you run into other issues, please add comments.

Comment: Thanks Paul. I've not got this updated yet: `<developer allowIntranetProxyAccess="true" allowSSOFeature="true" enabled="true">
` so will update & try again.

Comment: That's how I've got things setup at the moment. The developer bootstrap page doesn't work though :(

Comment: waiting on a response from team... but it should work, I understand we use this internally for testing.

Comment: also change  <security whitelistEnabled="true" featureAdminEnabled="true"> to  <security whitelistEnabled="false" featureAdminEnabled="true"> ... this is what we do in our automation test

Comment: Yes, I've got that set. Still not working unfortunately. I'm seeing console output like this though: `DEPRECATED: lconn.core.util.LCDeferred Use dojo.Deferred instead -- will be removed in version: 5.0` which can't be good on a v5.0 system

Comment: it's a benign thing related to the AMD loader.  Email me and we'll get a dev to look at it with you.

Comment: From Development --- Most likely scenario is that they haven't created a binding for the way the gadget runs on the Bootstrap page.  It's is sensitive to the exact gadget URL, query params, etc.

My suggestion is for them to look at the makeRequest that's failing and find the "gadget" param on the POST.
.../opensocial/gadgets/makeRequest

And then use the wsadmin commands to verify the binding exists (or create it.)
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYGQH_5.0.0/admin/customize/r_admin_common_oauth_config_homepage_gadgets.dita?lang=en